# Снова contenteditable

Tags: contenteditable, javascript

Всё мучаюсь с этим редактором, но почти всё что нужно, реализовал как-то )

http://jsfiddle.net/nn2KX/1/

Выделите слово "текст" и нажмите например Подчеркнуть. Так вот, само браузерное выделение после подчеркивания пропадает, то есть:

[image]

Но однако с button всё нормально - http://jsfiddle.net/nn2KX/2/

Вот и хочу узнать, может как-то можно обойтись без button для этого дела?

Comment: [Preserve text selection in contenteditable...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315824/). Сохраняйте выделение, когда надо восстанавливайте...

Comment: > реализовал как-то

XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так это, добавьте

```
return false;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nn2KX/3/

Comment: @lampa, как всё просто :) В очередной раз выручили!